# How to upload files larger than 10mb via google cloud http functions. ? Any alternative options?

Tags: node.js, http, google-cloud-functions

I have made a google cloud function to upload the file into google bucket and returns signed URL in response.

Whenever large files (more than 10mb) uploaded. It is not working. 
It works fine for files less than 10mb.

I have searched and see in [cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits). It says max data sent size is 10mb for HTTP functions not allowed to increase size.

```
resource: {…}  
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "Function execution could not start, status: 'request too large'"  
 timestamp:  "2019-06-25T06:26:41.731015173Z"
```

for successful file upload, it gives below log
Function execution took 271 ms, finished with status code: 200

for large files, it gives below log
Function execution could not start, status: 'request too large'

Are there any alternative options to upload file in the bucket using API? Any different service would be fine. I need to upload file up to 20mb files. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could upload directly to a Google Cloud Storage bucket using the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) for web and mobile clients.  Then, you can use a [Storage trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage) to deal with the file after it's finished uploading.

Comment: This is not an option if you need more complex security.

Comment: @NickJ Security doesn't seem to be part of the question as written.  This question is simply asking for any alternative or workaround to the stated limit.  If you have more specific requirements, I suggest asking a new question and make clear what are the specific constraints you're working with.